# SharePoint Online : add a call to phone hyperlink to a page

Tags: html, sharepoint, hyperlink, sharepoint-online

I would like to add a hyperlink to a SharePoint modern page, which will call someone's number when clicked on mobile.

In HTML, these hyperlink are as such :

```
 <a href="tel:+05890000111">0-589-0000111</a>
```

(source : [W3Docs](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/how-to-add-telephone-links-with-html.html))

But, unfortunately, the "add link" pop up does not recognize the address. "This type of hyperlinks is not supported"
[image: SP online hyperlink Pop-up]

I tried `callto:tel:+Number`, I tried `tel:+Number`

This action will be performed by basic SharePoint users, not programmer ones, so it needs to be standard.

**Is there a way to do add a clickable phone number to SP online**, which will call someone?

Thanks :)

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=sharepoint+clickable+phone+number). . I got this https://sharepointlessons.wordpress.com/2019/02/11/telephone-links-in-sharepoint/

but actually it is a question for SuperUser and not StackOverflow

Comment: @mplungjan : thanks for the reminder, it's true I haven't posted since 1year... Oh, you found the exact same results I found on the internet ! Unfortunately, this does not answer my question on how to add a clickable phone number easily for a standard user. Maybe MS did not implement it yet.